# How to update output automatically

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

can anyone help me how to auto update whats inside the output in my `textbox` if i change the `values` in the table in the database without refreshing the page or click the `button` again to execute the script.

current script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_search_form').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $(".search_form_input").val('');
            $(".empty_batchcode").html("Doesn't exist!");

         $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            type:"GET",
            data: { term : $('#query').val() },
            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function(result) {

            var ii = 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                        $('#funiq_id').html(result[i].value).show();
                        $('#t_region').val(result[i].region).show();
                        $('#t_town').val(result[i].town).show();
                        $('#t_uniq_id').val(result[i].uniq_id).show();
                        $('#t_position').val(result[i].position).show();
                        $('#t_salary_grade').val(result[i].salary_grade).show();
                        $('#t_salary').val(result[i].salary).show();
                        $('#id'+ii+'').val(result[i].atid).show();
                        $('#aic'+ii+'').val(result[i].atic).show();
                        $('#name'+ii+'').val(result[i].atname).show();
                        $('#other_qual'+ii+'').val(result[i].other_sum).show();
                        $('#interview'+ii+'').val(result[i].interview_sum).show();
                ii++;
                }

            }

        });

    });
});      
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ajax call in a separate function . Then call `setInterval` on it

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer ;
$('#send_search_form').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".search_form_input").val('');
        $(".empty_batchcode").html("Doesn't exist!");
        clearInterval(timer);
        updateTextboxes();

});

function updateTextboxes(){
          $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#query').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

        var ii = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                    $('#funiq_id').html(result[i].value).show();
                    $('#t_region').val(result[i].region).show();
                    $('#t_town').val(result[i].town).show();
                    $('#t_uniq_id').val(result[i].uniq_id).show();
                    $('#t_position').val(result[i].position).show();
                    $('#t_salary_grade').val(result[i].salary_grade).show();
                    $('#t_salary').val(result[i].salary).show();
                    $('#id'+ii+'').val(result[i].atid).show();
                    $('#aic'+ii+'').val(result[i].atic).show();
                    $('#name'+ii+'').val(result[i].atname).show();
                    $('#other_qual'+ii+'').val(result[i].other_sum).show();
                    $('#interview'+ii+'').val(result[i].interview_sum).show();
            ii++;
            }


        if(timer == 1){ // if timer has been cleared

            timer = setInterval(updateTextboxes,1000); // <-- change 1000 to the value you want
        }

        }


    });


}
timer = setInterval(updateTextboxes,1000);
});      
 </script>
```

Comment: why is it its kinda lagy after a few seconds in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the MVVM pattern where html and datamodels are bound.

There are a few libraries that can help you with this

- http://knockoutjs.com/
- http://angularjs.org/

http://www.faridesign.net/2012/04/20-javascript-frameworks-mvvm-templating-licenses-etc/

I'd advice you to start with youtube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F233-PRVcW8

If you want to go deeper in the rabbit hole there is also websockets, but they will in their turn rely on mvvm. In your case this would be an alternative http://socketo.me/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. take all the ajax stuff in to a function and call it when needed. If you have a lot of template-ing to do i suggest using knockout.js or angular.js it will make things so much easier.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_search_form').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        refresh();
    });
    $(".search_form_input").on('keyup',function(){
        refresh();
    });
});     

function refresh(){
    $(".empty_batchcode").html("Doesn't exist!");
    $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#query').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

        var ii = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                    $('#funiq_id').html(result[i].value).show();
                    $('#t_region').val(result[i].region).show();
                    $('#t_town').val(result[i].town).show();
                    $('#t_uniq_id').val(result[i].uniq_id).show();
                    $('#t_position').val(result[i].position).show();
                    $('#t_salary_grade').val(result[i].salary_grade).show();
                    $('#t_salary').val(result[i].salary).show();
                    $('#id'+ii+'').val(result[i].atid).show();
                    $('#aic'+ii+'').val(result[i].atic).show();
                    $('#name'+ii+'').val(result[i].atname).show();
                    $('#other_qual'+ii+'').val(result[i].other_sum).show();
                    $('#interview'+ii+'').val(result[i].interview_sum).show();
            ii++;
            }

        }

    });
} 
</script>
```

Comment: i removed the line  $(".search_form_input").val('');. does it give you an error on the console ?